# How can fragment in fragmentStatePagerAdapter get data from Fragment hosting the viewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, communication, greenrobot-eventbus

`FragmentHost` has `ViewPager`, and Fragments of viewpager need data from `FragmentHost` to create their views.

How to get the data. The data is custom Class.

One way is using `Serializable` implementation of the custom class. But I want to avoid that, as the class contains array and Map of other custom classes.

Also there can be multiple instances of `FragmentHost` active at a time, one `FragmentHost` per activity.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out for communication

```
    public class CrimePagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.android.ankitt.criminalintent.activities.extra.crime.id";

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private List<Crime> mCrimes;


    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CrimePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);


        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.actvity_crime_pager_view_pager);
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);

                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++) {

            if (mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId)) {

                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
    public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID, crimeId);


        CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*mCrime = new Crime();*/


        /*UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CrimeActivity.EXTRA_CRIME_ID);*/
        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID);

        mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);

        mFilePhoto = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getPhotoFile(mCrime);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mEditText.setText(mCrime.getTitile()); //Updating Crime fragment with crime
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                mCrime.setTitile(toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


        final Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        /*pickContact.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);*/
        mSuspectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_suspect);

        mSuspectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(pickContact, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });

        mReportButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_report);

        mReportButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getCrimeReport());
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.crime_report_subject));
                intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.send_report));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        updateDate((mCrime.getDate()).toString());
        /*mDateButton.setEnabled(false);*/
/* Design a date picker for an  application */
        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                /*DatePickerFragment dialog = new DatePickerFragment();*/

                DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());

                dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);

                dialog.show(fragmentManager, DIALOG_DATE);
            }
        });

        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved()); //Updating Crime fragment with crime
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        if (mCrime.getSuspect() != null) {

            mSuspectButton.setText(mCrime.getSuspect());
        }

        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager.resolveActivity(pickContact, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) == null) {
            mSuspectButton.setEnabled(false);
        }


        mImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_camera);
        final Intent captureImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) ;
        boolean canTakePhoto = mFilePhoto != null &&
                captureImage.resolveActivity(packageManager)!=null;
        mImageButton.setEnabled(canTakePhoto);

        if (canTakePhoto){

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mFilePhoto);
            captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
        }

        mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(captureImage,REQUEST_PHOTO);
            }
        });
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_photo);
        updatePhotoView();
        return view;
    }

    public void returnResult() {
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
            Date date = (Date) data
                    .getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
            mCrime.setDate(date);
            updateDate(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && data != null) {

            Uri contactUri = data.getData();

            String[] queryFields = new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            };

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String suspect = cursor.getString(0);
                mCrime.setSuspect(suspect);
                mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO){
            updatePhotoView();
        }
    }

    private void updateDate(String text) {
        mDateButton.setText(text);
    }

    private String getCrimeReport() {
        String solvedString = null;
        if (mCrime.isSolved()) {
            solvedString = getString(R.string.crime_report_solved);
        } else {
            solvedString = getString(R.string.crime_report_unsolved);
        }


        String dateFormat = "EEE, MM dd";

        String dateString = DateFormat.format(dateFormat, mCrime.getDate()).toString();

        String suspect = mCrime.getSuspect();
        if (suspect == null) {
            suspect = getString(R.string.crime_report_no_suspect);
        } else {
            suspect = getString(R.string.crime_report_suspect, suspect);
        }

        String report = getString(R.string.crime_report, mCrime.getTitile(), dateString, solvedString, suspect);
        return report;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


        CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).updateCrime(mCrime);
    }

    private void updatePhotoView() {
        if (mFilePhoto == null || !mFilePhoto.exists()) {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        } else {
            Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(
                    mFilePhoto.getPath(), getActivity());
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

}
```